# View controller uses one nib fine but crashes with another

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, nib

I'm working on a universal app and the iPhone version works just fine. I created a new nib for iPad and set the files owner to be the viewcontroller class. The I connected all the IBOutlets and IBActions. When I run the app on an iPad (and in the iPad simulator) it crashes when I touch any of the controls. I tried setting break points in the IBActions for each but it doesn't even make it to those before the crash happens. What's going on?

Backtrace:
    * thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x0189809b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15, stop reason =  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x15)
    frame #0: 0x0189809b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15
    frame #1: 0x0020f14e UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    frame #2: 0x0020f0e6 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] +     61
    frame #3: 0x002b5ade UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    frame #4: 0x002b5fa7 UIKit`-[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +     503
    frame #5: 0x002b5b13 UIKit`-[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 48
    frame #6: 0x00304462 UIKit`-[UISegmentedControl _setSelectedSegmentIndex:notify:] +         684
    frame #7: 0x00305dd0 UIKit`-[UISegmentedControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 1026
    frame #8: 0x002342cf UIKit`-[UIWindow *sendTouchesForEvent:] + 272
    frame #9: 0x002345e6 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
    frame #10: 0x0021adc4 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 464
    frame #11: 0x0020e634 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 8196
    frame #12: 0x021c0ef5 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 1274
    frame #13: 0x012a1195 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    frame #14: 0x01205ff2 CoreFoundation`*_CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    frame #15: 0x012048da CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2218
    frame #16: 0x01203d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    frame #17: 0x01203c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #18: 0x021bf7d8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 190
    frame #19: 0x021bf88a GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 103
    frame #20: 0x0020c626 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1163
    frame #21: 0x00001d8d gravity`main + 141 at main.m:16

Comment: What's the error message that you get?

Comment: There isn't one, it just crashes in main.m. I'm using lldb if that makes a difference.

Comment: If the debugger stops on UIApplicationMain in your main.m file, it's usually due to an exception -- you'll find details about the exception printed in the debug console.

Comment: The console doesn't print anything when it crashes but see the question for the backtrace.

Comment: If you could post some of the actual code, it would help us to analyze the error.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. See my answer for what was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the view controller wasn't being retained due to ARC. So when I went back to send messages to it it crashed.

Comment: I had to wait the two days to answer my own; that was my intention though.